# What is the logical statement for C ⊆ A ∪ B in an equation?

Tags: proof-writing

Set C is a subset of A union B. 1 is in set A, then also a union with B gives {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
We know – A U B is { x | x є A) v (x є B)
C ⊑ is a subset of A U B which means every element in A U B is also C.
Ɐ є { x | x є A) v (x є B)
Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but $C \subseteq A\cup B$ means any element $x \in C$ is in $A$ or $B$.

Comment: write in logical symbols (using Ɐ, ﾖ, etc.) And then showing that the resulting formulas are equivalent.

Comment: @Nichole Reed every element in C will be in AUB

Comment: It is a little challenging to read your OP with as is since you don't mention what $A$, $B$ area or what $C$ is. Although that may not be important, I can't se what is the relevance of $1$, or $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ in your conclusion. Now, If  I understood correctly, your conclusion was that every element of $A\cup B$ is in $C$. That is false.

But here is my stab at it, replacing  quantifier and logical symbols with English words.

$$A\cup B=\{x:x\in A\quad\text{or}\quad x\in B\}$$

$C\subset A\cup B$ means that
$$\text{for all} x, \quad x\in C\quad \text{implies}\quad x\in A\cup B$$

Comment: The original question is  C\ a⊆b
 write in logical symbols (using Ɐ, ﾖ, etc.) And then showing that the resulting formulas are equivalent.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write with MathJax. I just rollback your question to the original one.

Comment: Oliver Diaz, How did you get that?